# Angular 2: get all <img> tags inside specific div

Tags: angular

I need a function to get all images inside a specific div, I tried to use `BrowserDomAdapter` but it's throwing this error `el.querySelector is not a function`, infact I haven't declared any `el` variable in my component

```
import { BrowserDomAdapter} from '@angular/platform-browser/src/browser/browser_adapter';
...
...
constructor(private dom:BrowserDomAdapter){
}
ngAfterContentInit(){
    this.lightboxImages();
}
lightboxImages(){
    let dom = new BrowserDomAdapter();
    let images = dom.querySelector('img','.post-body');
    console.log(images);
}
```

**Update**

If I have the `<img>` tags inside a variable, how can I get the images from it?

```
export class Post{

   post:Post;

   @Input()
   set data(data:any) {
     this.post = new Post(data); 
     this.lightboxImages(this.post.content());
   }

   lightboxImages(content:any){
       let images = content. ???
       console.log(images);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`BrowserDomAdapter` is not supposed to be used. It's for Angular internal use only.

I assume you want to query elements passed as children because you use `ngAfterContentInit`:

```ts
@Component({
  ...
  template: `
  ...
  <div #wrapper>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </div>
  ...
`
})
export class MyComponent {
  @ViewChild('wrapper') wrapper:ElementRef;
  ngAfterContentInit(){
    this.lightboxImages();
  }
  lightboxImages(){
    let images = this.wrapper.nativeElement.querySelector('img','.post-body');
    console.log(images);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can't I use `@ContentChildren` for this case? `@ContentChildren('.post-body')`

Comment: Yes you can use it.b ut need to see how does your template look like?

Comment: No, you can't use CSS selectors with `@ContentChildren()`. If the elements you want to query have a template variable like above `#wrapper` then you can use the name of the template variable to query for these elements directly using `@ContentChildren()`. I assumed this is not desired because it makes the element more cumbersome to use.

Comment: one more thing, if I have these `img` tags inside a variable `post.content`, isn't it better to pass it to `lightboxImages(content:any)` instead of getting it from the dom?

Comment: Sure, direct DOM access (`.nativeElement`) should always be the last option.

Comment: Can you add this function to your answer, thanks alot.

Comment: I don't understand your update. What do you try to accomplish with the reference to the image tags anyway? It sounds like you're adding the image tags using `[innerHTML]="..."` or similar. Can you please explain better what you're doging.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I'm implementing lightbox component to display the images of a post response, `post.content()` will return the `innerHTML`. but since I have the response as a variable, why would I get it from the DOM

Comment: If you have the response as String that you add using `[innerHTML]` then you only have a string but not elements. Only after adding the string using `[innerHTML]` the string becomes elements. If you need the elements you first need to add the string to the DOM. "Implementing a lightbox component" doesn't tell me much. What I need to know is what you need the reference to the elements for.

Comment: yupp exactly,  `<div class="post-body" [innerHtml]="post.content()">`, lightbox component communicate with all components using appState service, so all I need to do after I get the `<img>` elements as an object  is to pass it to the service `appState.set('lightboxImgs', lightboxImages(this.post.content()));`

Comment: So we are back to square one. But passing the image element to the service isn't a very detailed description about what you need the reference to the image tag for. It would be better you add the image tag using `*ngFor` and use Angular2 bindings to update their state according to the state in the service instead the other way around.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I will post this in details in another question

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer here it is  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38716925/implementing-lightbox-in-angular2

Answer (score -1):

> this.containerBlock.nativeElement.getElementsByTagName("img")

Where containerBlock is template reference. This will return all the img tag inside div with template reference containerBlock.